# Kafka - How to obtain failed messages details in Producer class

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

Kafka allows for asynchronous message sending through below methods on Producer (KafkaProducer) class:

```
public java.util.concurrent.Future<RecordMetadata> send(ProducerRecord<K,V> record) 
public java.util.concurrent.Future<RecordMetadata> send(ProducerRecord<K,V> record, Callback callback)
```

**Successes can be handled through**
1) the `Future<RecordMetaData>` object or
2) `onCompletion` method invoked by the callback. Full method signature and usage of `onCompletion` is as below ([taken from kafka docs](https://kafka.apache.org/090/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/KafkaProducer.html))

`

```
ProducerRecord<byte[],byte[]> record = new ProducerRecord<byte[],byte[]>("the-topic", key, value);  
producer.send(record,
               new Callback() {
                   public void onCompletion(RecordMetadata metadata, Exception e) {
                       if(e != null)
                           e.printStackTrace();
                       System.out.println("The offset of the record we just sent is: " + metadata.offset());
                   }
               });
```

**While failure needs to be handled through the `Exception e` passed to the `onCompletion` method**

Fine every thing looks good so far.

But if I am getting it right, any reasonable information that can be obtained from `exception` or `e` object is stacktrace and exception message.  What I mean to point out here is, `e` does not contain any information of the actual record sent. Or in other words, it does not contain a reference to the actual `record` that was sent to kafka broker. So what useful processing or handling can be done by the producer if the `record` was not sent successfully. Really not much. 
Why I say this is - **ideally I would like to make a log of the failed message some where and then try to resend it. But with the little information (`e`) provided by framework, i feel this is not possible.**

Can someone point out if I am right or wrong?

Comment: as a note I want to mention that, i don't mean to say that exception `e` is not helpful. It is certainly help full for debugging and so in finding the cause of error. But what I am not sure is does it contain enough information to determine which `record` has failed so I could resend or log that `record`

Comment: Give a try to following version of Callback class:

    class CallbackFunc implements Callback {
 private int recordId;

 public CallbackFunc(int recordId) {
  this.recordId = recordId;
 }
 
 @Override
 public void onCompletion(RecordMetadata metadata, Exception e) {
  if(e != null) {
   Log.error("Error writing message to Kafka. Record ID: " + recordId);
  }
 }
}

Answer (score 2):

You could easily create a callback that receives the `producerRecord` as a constructor argument. So upon `onCompletion` with an exception, you can have complete knowledge of the producer record, and even try to send it again.

I dealt with the same issue. Created a callback that gets both `producerRecord`, and a callback handler that uses an executor service to send the record again. So eventually, I can tolerate any number of failures (e.g. network issues or kafka is down), and recover from it.