# In Kafka if the parameter "retries" is set to 1 or more, then are retries made automatically?

Tags: hadoop, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

The `retries` parameter as it states

> Setting a value greater than zero will cause the client to resend any record whose send fails with a potentially transient error. Note that this retry is no different than if the client resent the record upon receiving the error.

What I want to confirm is are the retries made automatically by the kafka framework or any additional handling is required from the client side.
And if it's done automatically, and say `retries` is set to `1`. And if the sending of `record` fails on second attempt also, then will kafka inform me differently with appropriate error messages when it's going to retry and when it's going to stop retrying.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you are right, the retries are made automatically by the Kafka client without the need for any additional handling by the user application.
The client library doesn't inform you when it's going to retry but it follows your configuration with the `retry.backoff.ms` parameter which defines "The amount of time to wait before attempting to retry a failed request to a given topic partition" as described in the official documentation.
When all the attempts fail then you will receive an exception in the callback passed to the KafkaProducer `send` method (with RecordMetadata null because no record was sent) or through the Future returned by send.

Comment: would you like to comment on: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45528743/kafka-how-to-obtain-failed-messages-details-in-producer-class. I need to provide a kafka based solution in my company immediately, so sorry for intrusion.